# How to create a teams card using external webservice and post data in power automate(Part 2)

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards

This is a continuation of my other question:
[My first question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G39gQ.png)

What I am trying to accomplish:

1. User enters a mention
2. My web service creates an adaptive card form with custom data (same schema)
3. presents the card to my user
4. user enters some data
5. Submit sends this form data to my web service for processing

Here is the card (the result of the 1st http) I am sending in reply to mention

```
        $var = '{
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "version": "1.2",
        "msTeams": {
            "width": "full"
        },
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Adaptive Card Example",
                "wrap": true,
                "size": "large",
                "weight": "bolder",
                "id": "title"
            },
            {
                "type": "Input.Text",
                "placeholder": "Provide your thoughts",
                "separator": true,
                "isMultiline": true,
                "id": "thoughts"
            },
            {
                "type": "ActionSet",
                "separator": true,
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "Submit",
                        "style": "positive",
                        "id": "submit"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    ';
```

[image: My power flow automation]

How do i get to the value of input.text with the id of thoughts?  everything i see, it ends up blank.

I am not sure what else you need to help, i can edit/post anything else.

***EDIT**

this is my dynamic dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make use of the dynamic content presented to you that is taken directly from your adaptive card definition ...

[image: Dynamic Properties]

If the dynamic property doesn't exist, the easiest way to get the result is to simply refer to it using an expression ...

```
body('Post_adaptive_card_and_wait_for_a_response')?['data']?['thoughts']
```

... you could do the work to fully qualify the dynamic properties but in this case, it seems like overkill.

This is the output after I completed the card in my Teams channel ...

[image: Result]

Comment: see my edit about dynamic dropdown

Comment: And if you scroll down?

Comment: just the standard teams options (Team id, channel id, message) etc

Comment: Check out my updated answer.

Comment: id put "body('Post_adaptive_card_and_wait_for_a_response')?['data']?['thoughts']" in the initial value of initialize?

Comment: Yes, but you need to make sure you put it in to the **Expression** tab as the value there.  If you run it, in the output of the run, you can see the JSON that comes back from the adaptive card response.  The expression I've provided is merely the path to that node in the JSON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244005/discussion-between-bart2puck-and-skin).